# modify previous commit without changing timestamp

Tags: git, github, git-commit

To modify the previous commit I can run the commit on my staged changes

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push -f
```

The commit has been modified but the timestamp of the commit changes...

Is there a way **not** to change the timestap?. Something like:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit --no-time-change
```

Comment: Are you confusing Git with GitHub?

Comment: The only way to be able to set dates on commits (author or commit dates) is by using environment variables. Look at **committing** https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `git commit --amend` does not *modify* a commit; instead, it makes a *new-and-improved commit* and stops using the old-and-lousy one.  This distinction matters if anyone else, or any other branch, has access to the original commit, because they won't switch over to the new-and-improved commit.  The new commit has a new and different hash ID; all the users of the old commit are using the old hash ID, which is unchanged.  For these reasons, the fact that the date changes is usually unimportant.

That said:  There are *two* timestamps in each commit:

- the author date, and
- the committer date.

When using `git commit`, with or without `--amend`, you can use `--date=<whatever>` to specify the author date, but there's no *flag* for specifying the committer date.

Fortunately, there are two *environment variables* that you can set that override both committer and author dates.  These are `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`.  They accept the same date formats that `--date` accepts, and that `git show --pretty=fuller` shows for both the dates, for instance.

Using either `eval` (which is a bit dangerous in general) or `env`, we can have sh/bash-compatible shells do this for us as a one-liner:

```sh
eval $(git log --no-walk --format='GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="%ad" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="%cd"') git commit --amend
```

or:

```sh
env GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$(git log --no-walk --format=%ad)" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git log --no-walk --format=%cd)" git commit --amend
```

The `eval` method is a bit shorter and invokes `git` fewer times but does mean you must be careful about the command itself.  As long as the command itself is just `git commit --amend`, the whole thing works well, so you could make this a Git alias (remember the leading `!` to force Git to pass it to a shell).

(Replace `--no-walk` with `-1` if you like.  Note that either way we're relying on the fact that without a starting point, `git log` assumes `HEAD`.)

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you